# Why is my object.save working in one place and failing in another?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

Could someone tell me why this works:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mysql2'

@inverters=Inverter.where(:mac=>@mac)
Inverter.transaction do
  @inverters.each do |inverter|
    inverter.ip = @client_ip
    inverter.save               # Object is saved:)!
  end
end
```

But this does not?:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mysql2'

@outputs=<a two dimensional hash>
Output.transaction do
  @outputs.each do |out|           
    @newOut = Output.new
    @newOut.inverter_id = out[:inverter_id]
    @newOut.eac = out[:eac]
    @newOut.pac = out[:pac]
    @newOut.vac = out[:vac]
    @newOut.iac = out[:iac]
    @newOut.epv = out[:epv]
    @newOut.ppv = out[:ppv]
    @newOut.vpv = out[:vpv]   
    @newOut.save                   # Object fails to save to db:(.

    # 2 lines of other code
  end
end
```

Both objects save successfully when I enter the same commands manually in the rails console, but the second one fails within my script. I have done extensive debugging making sure that all variables ('out' and '@outputs') have expected values and again it is all working in the console. I am using Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 3.0.3 and mysql2 gem version 0.2.7. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Try changing your `save` call to `save!` - they are identical, except `save` returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the save was successful or not.  `save!` throws an exception when saving fails which details the reasons for the failure, or just saves normally if saving worked.  This makes it great for debugging problems like this!

Comment: great i'll try that! also i forgot to mention that the '@newOut.save' is returning true even though i can see that it is not saving upon examination of the db. do you know how this would happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I did to figure this out was to open up a separate tab in terminal, navigate to my rails app folder and follow what was going on with mySQL behind the scenes by typing the following line: tail -f log/development.log. I could see on running the second not working script above, in the log that after the INSERT into outputs table line, it would just say 'ROLLBACK'. The reason this was happening was that I had two lines of random code after my @newOut.save statement. When I took those two lines out of the transaction loop, everything worked. This is clearly a total newbie error, but I hope it helps someone.